# How to set an object to context so that i can get it anywhere in the application with @Context

Tags: java, rest, jetty, jersey-2.0, dropwizard

I want to set `MyObject` class instance to the application context so that I can use it anywhere with the following:

`@Context MyObject object`

I used `Jedis` which gives me access for the `jedis` through the above approach.

Please help in setting the context.

I am using `dropwizard (jetty,jersery and jackson)`.

Comment: That sounds like a misuse of context. Does your MyObject actually have any context information? This sounds more like a job for an injection framework

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please have a better title and more detailed information in the content with your effort to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had some time and wrote up the way to do it (jersey only, no other DI framework used).

Jersey is compliant with javax.inject annotations. The reason you do NOT use a context annotation is because (by the sound of it) your MyObject class is not a context object (e.g. it doesn't change with each request like e.g. HttpServletRequest which is injectable). So we need to bind your object.

Consider my implementation of MyObject:

```
public class MyObject {

    String get() {
        return "I am an object"; 
    }
}
```

This object needs to be available in my jersey classes (resource, filter etc). I wrote a little resource using this bean:

```
@Path("context")
public class ContextResource {

    @Inject
    MyObject o;

    @GET
    public String get() {
        return o.get();
    }

}
```

Note that I am using the javax.inject.Inject annotation for this case to tell jersey I want this particular bean injected. 
All I need to do now is to tell jersey about this bean. In my DW application I do:

```
public class Application extends io.dropwizard.Application<Configuration>{  

    @Override
    public void run(Configuration configuration, Environment environment) throws Exception {

        environment.jersey().register(ContextResource.class);
        environment.jersey().register(new AbstractBinder() {

            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                bind(MyObject.class).to(MyObject.class);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Application().run("server", "/home/artur/dev/repo/sandbox/src/main/resources/config/test.yaml");
    }
}
```

Note that I am using a binder to bind my bean. The syntax looks funky, but essentially it is doing a "bind the type to the implementation". Since my type is my implementation (I am not using an interface for MyObject), this looks like:

```
bind(MyObject.class).to(MyObject.class)
```

Now jersey knows about my bean and will happily inject it.

Running all my code prints:

```
artur@pandaadb:~/dev/vpn$ curl localhost:9085/api/context
I am an object
```

Hope that brings some insights on how to use injection without a framework. Personally I would recommend using guice with dropwizard (google: dropwizard-guicey) which makes these kind of things very easy.

Regards,

Artur

Comment: I am having a TestClass and initializing it from the resource class. Inside TestClass I have injected as you said but the instance is alwasy null. BUt I am able to access the injected instance if I inject  it in the Resource class.

Comment: TestClass is not injected because it is not created by jersey, it is created by you. Jersey knows nothing about it and therefore won't inject it.

Comment: No You got me wrong. I am injecting MyObject in my TestClass but it is always null. I could not access MyObject's memebers from TestClass.

Comment: If you want MyObject to be injected in TestClass, then TestClass and MyObject must be bound to jersey, and TestClass must be created by Jersey. Both need to be in the abstractBinder and both need to be bound as .class, not as complete object. Jersey will not inject objects that you create manually

Comment: Then what should I do in my case? I want the MyObject to be available through my entire application. Is SIngleton the only chance?

Comment: You need to read up on dependency injection frameworks. You can bind your MyObject in the jersey binder like above, but this will NOT make it available everywhere. This ONLY makes it available in jersey managed classes (filters, resources etc). If you need to access that outside the scope, you need to use a regular singleton (bad) or use an injection framework that bridges jersey and the rest of your application (e.g. guice). Look into https://github.com/xvik/dropwizard-guicey for fully integrated DI with jersey and google guice